# List of nodes instance prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Is it possible get list of nodes instance with prometheus. I have a node exporter but I don't see metrics like that.

Should we add a new operator?

Comment: Take a look at https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus/#monitoringthekubernetesnodeswithprometheus

Answer (score 3):

You can use [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) for this purpose.

> kube-state-metrics is about generating metrics from Kubernetes API
>   objects without modification. This ensures, that features provided by
>   kube-state-metrics have the same grade of stability as the Kubernetes
>   API objects themselves. In turn this means, that kube-state-metrics in
>   certain situations may not show the exact same values as kubectl, as
>   kubectl applies certain heuristics to display comprehensible messages.
>   kube-state-metrics exposes raw data unmodified from the Kubernetes
>   API, this way users have all the data they require and perform
>   heuristics as they see

You can find node metrics [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/node-metrics.md).
For example:

```
Metric name: kube_node_info
node=<node-address> 
kernel_version=<kernel-version> 
os_image=<os-image-name> 
container_runtime_version=<container-runtime-and-version-combination> 
kubelet_version=<kubelet-version> 
kubeproxy_version=<kubeproxy-version> 
provider_id=<provider-id
```