# How to get number of nodes running in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to create an alert in which, when the number of nodes increase or decrease I'll send an alert.

currently, I can get the node's count using this:

```
count(kube_node_info)
```

but I want to get the node's count for 5 mins and 1min so that I can do the subtraction and sent the alert. I don't know how to get the count of nodes for a 5m time frame.

Comment: i know it's kinda late but does this work? `abs(sum(kube_node_info) - sum(kube_node_info offset 1m)) > 0`

curious why you want an alert for that though.

Comment: I have enabled autoscaling. So just wanted to have an alert when Node upscale or downs scale

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would create two different alerts.

```
(sum(kube_node_info) > sum(kube_node_info offset 1d)) # more nodes than 1 day ago
(sum(kube_node_info) < sum(kube_node_info offset 1d)) # less nodes than 1 day ago
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
# alert --> "The number of nodes has changed"
(sum(kube_node_info) > sum(kube_node_info offset 1d)) or (sum(kube_node_info) < sum(kube_node_info offset 1d))
```

Meanwhile, `kube_node_info` is delivered by `kube-state-metrics`, meaning that these metrics are generated by the Kubernetes API (see [List of nodes instance prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223227/list-of-nodes-instance-prometheus)). Another way to monitor the number of running nodes might be as follows:

```
# alert --> "less nodes than 1 day ago"
(count(up{instance=~"node.*"}) < count(count by (node) (min_over_time(up{instance=~"node.*"}[1d]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the [delta](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) function or the [offset](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier) modifier to get what you want.

Comment: tried delta function. Not working. delta(sum(kube_node_info)[2h]) and delta((kube_node_info)[2h]) but I am getting the error

Comment: What error are you getting with delta(kube_node_info[2h])?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
abs(sum(kube_node_info) - sum(kube_node_info offset 1m)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count(count by (node) (kube_node_info))
```